# Highlight all occurrences of a word in Github's Atom text editor

Tags: text-editors, highlighting, atom-editor

In Sublime Text, if you double-click a word in file, all occurrences of that word are highlighted on the page, giving at-a-glance orientation of how a variable or other text is used in the file.

Is there an equivalent shortcut in the Atom text editor?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found this Atom package called [highlight-selected](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-selected) I have been using it since a few days ago and it's working like a charm!

To install it, go to the command line and do:

```
apm install highlight-selected
```

Make sure to restart Atom and boom!